Is it possible to delete buckets in AWS S3 with only the access key ID?
As far as I’m aware, the Access Key ID is like a username, and without the Access Key Secret it’s useless?
Even if the associated user has full S3 permissions?
Is there anyway other than a 0day aws exploit that you can manage/delete everything without having the secret?

You are correct. When making API calls to AWS the authentication process requires:

Access Key: An identifier that looks like AKIAIOSFODNN7ABCDEFG. It's okay if other people see it. It is connected to your AWS account and is typically associated with an IAM User.
Secret Key: A randomized string that is like a password. Never reveal it to other people.

You need both of these to make API requests in your AWS account.
In contrast, logging into the AWS management console requires:

An AWS Account number (or account Alias)
Username (which can be an email address or other easy-to-read string)
Password (created by the user)

If a user successfully authenticates to the AWS management console then they can perform operations in the AWS Account.
In both cases (API call & console), their ability to create/modify/delete resources in the AWS Account depends upon the permissions that were assigned to their access credentials. By default users have no permissions, so the ability to Delete an Amazon S3 Bucket would require an IAM administrator to assign permissions to the user to be able to perform this operation, or a Bucket Policy would need to be added to the Amazon S3 bucket to give such permissions.

Thank you :) no worries if not, I can go digging - but are you aware of any AWS docs that spell this out to pass over to some non techs?

It's deeply technical, but the documentation on signing AWS API calls should explain the need.  You use the secret key to communicate with AWS services, and without that, there's no way to communicate.

@owenmelbz What is your actual goal here? Are you saying that some 'non-techs' are worried about security in the cloud? If so, take a look here: Cloud Security – Amazon Web Services (AWS) You'll find lots of security whitepapers that show the cloud can actually be safer than a normal data center.
